# Populate Dataset tables when accessed

Tags: c#, database, winforms, performance, dataset

I have a C# dataset that is loaded from the database with a large amount of data when the application starts.
This slows down the application startup.
I want to leave the dataset tables empty and populate them from the database once when the table is accessed for the first time, so any table remains empty until it is accessed for the first time.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do not do it in `Thread` or `Background Worker`?

Comment: We tried this in other scenarios but it has issues.

Comment: `When the table is accessed for the first time` - what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)

The simplest way to do it would be doing something like this at your service layer:

```
public class EmployeeManager : IEmployeeManager
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    private IEnumerable<Employee> _employees;

    public EmployeeManager(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return
            _employees ?? (_employees = _employeeRepository.GetAll());
    }
}
```

Note that the `_employees` collection gets populated only the first time the method `GetEmployees()` is called. So assuming that you have your data access code separated in a different layer you could just put this logic there and the data will only be populated once it's needed.

Another way to tackle this issue would be to implement Paging so that you only get the data you need in chunks instead of loading entire tables on memory, here's more info about that:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/PagingResults.aspx

Comment: This is ok if I am building the classes from beginnig, but the issue here is that strongly typed classes of the dataset tables are auto generated.